# wordpress plugin: form method='post' returns blank page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am writing a plugin that will upload a file, so I need to use method='post', but when I submit, I get a blank page back. method='get' works but not method='post'.

No info in the debug log. Any ideas why?